# jQuery and JSON issue

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json

I'm having an issue with the parser of jQuery when I give him a JSON string like this (java):

```
String JSONvalue = "[{"evaluationId":92688,"ResponseId":378501,"comment":"I can't do this ~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{\":?><\/.,;'[]\\=-0987654321`","rankingId":0}]";
```

and when I pass it to the parser (javascript), it looks like this:

```
var prevCommentsAndRankings =  jQuery.parseJSON('[{"evaluationId":92688,"ResponseId":378501,"comment":"I can't do this ~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{\":?><\/.,;'[]\\=-0987654321`","rankingId":0}]');
```

I'm getting error of invalid tokens, this is because of the ' " and [ ] on the JSON string. How could I handle them, consider that the JSON may always have special characters within. Thanks in advance !

Comment: you aren't escaping the characters that need to be escaped in the strings

Comment: Don't build the JSON yourself. Use `JSONArray` and `JSONObject`

Comment: This is the correctly escaped string for the `JS` portion: `'[{"evaluationId": 92688, "ResponseId": 378501, "comment": "I can\'t do this ~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{\\":?><\/.,;\'[]\=-0987654321\`", "rankingId":0}]'`

Comment: thanks for the feedback, ' " and \ have problems within, with the proper escaping they work !

Answer (score 0):

Just for the arbitrary strings replace the quote with it's HTML entity `&quot;` BEFORE rendering it in JSON and right after you parsed the JSON. Both are common function you can find in Java and Javascript.